# How to make a delay in a UWP with C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp

I'm new on this of C#, I don't know so much of it.
I'm trying to make an app that changes a TextBlock every second. The app is UWP and I'm using C#.
This is my code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool stop = false;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string input = TextInput.Text + " ";
            TextOutput.Text = input;
            string output = TextOutput.Text;

            for (int i = 0; i <50; i++)
            {
                output = output.Substring(1, output.Length - 1) + output[0];
                TextOutput.Text = output;
                Task.Delay(150);
            }
        }
    }
```

For now I've tryed `Task.Delay()`, `Thread.Sleep()` and others, but this doesn't stop the for-loop.
In fact, I've made the same app but for console, and the Thread.Sleep() works perfectly.
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, it's just that `Task.Delay` is a task, perhaps obviously. And you have to await (or continue) tasks:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string input = TextInput.Text + " ";
        TextOutput.Text = input;
        string output = TextOutput.Text;

        for (int i = 0; i <50; i++)
        {
            output = output.Substring(1, output.Length - 1) + output[0];
            TextOutput.Text = output;
            await Task.Delay(150);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! If I use an async void, the delay will work correctly?

Comment: Be careful though -- because of that `await` call, your code is reentrant. The user can click the button again while your loop is running.

Answer (score 0):

the value you are passing into Task.Delay / Thread.Sleep is going be milliseconds not seconds.

I would try Thread.sleep(1000) // this will you a delay of 1 second.

Comment: I've done this, but nothing. This stops the window but the program follow doing. This isn't a solution. :(